# Radio Button Values Not Showing Into Another Page Via Session?

Tags: php, forms, session, submit

i want to passing radio button values to another page via `session post variable` but problem is that in another page radio button values didn't display in the page via session

need to help to solve this issue thank you

**Index Page Function & Source Code**

**Php Function**

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['sizes1'][]=$_POST['size'];
?>
```

**Javascript Function**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $('.form-radios label').attr('checked', 'unchecked');
 $(".form-radios label").click(function(){
 $(this).attr('checked', 'checked').addClass('checked');
 $('label').not(this).removeClass('checked');
 });     
 });
```

**Index Page Form**

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<div class="form-radios">
<label>Small</label>
<input type="radio" name="size[]" id="small" value="small"/>
<label>Medium</label>
<input type="radio" name="size[]" id="medium" value="medium"/>
<label>Large</label>
<input type="radio" name="size[]" id="large" value="large"/>
<label>Xl</label>
<input type="radio" name="size[]" id="xl" value="xl"/>
</div><br />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

**Test Page Php Function**

```
<?php 
session_start();
echo $new_sizes=implode($_SESSION['sizes1']);

$max=count($new_sizes);
for($i=0; $i<=$max++; $i++)
{
?>
<input type="text" value="<?php $new_sizes [$i] ?>" />
<?php  } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing wrong post values i.e $_POST['image1'], $_POST['product'] etc does not physically exist in you form.

Comment: chandresh cool actually i reduced the way i didn't paste full form here just radio button div ...

Comment: just need to use it `if(isset($_REQUEST['addtocart']))` that's it